# Delete button/link not appearing after the file upload

Tags: fine-uploader, aws-php-sdk

After the image upload via fine uploader, delete button does not appears. I am not able to figure about the missing config, can some one help ?

JS

```
deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        method: "POST",
        endpoint: "http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php"
},
```

Template has the following:

```
<button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
   <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: If the delete button does not appear, either you have some CSS somewhere in your document that is hiding it, or your template is invalid in some way such that the delete button cannot be rendered, or perhaps some other JS error. What are you seeing in the JS console? What does the markup look like according to your browser?

Comment: You are right Ray! when inspected, I see place holder for delete button (actual image is not visible for some reason). Not sure which css make it invisible; I will do experiment later as delete functionality work through delete button is not visible.

Comment: @bizready, did you figure out what was causing for the delete icon to be invisible? thanks.

Comment: found the issue within the rails app. The fine_uploader css needs to account for asset_path for the various gifs. e.g. background: url(<%= asset_path 'retry.gif' %>); Also had to change the css file to .css.erb to make it effective.